# Passing unicode characters to Jython

Tags: java, python, unicode, jython

I am trying to run a python code on Jython, and this code contains some Unicode literals. I'd like to pass the code as a String (rather than load from a file).

It seems that upon exec() method call the unicode characters are converted to "?" characters:

```
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState());
System.out.println("ā".codePointAt(0)); // outputs 257
interp.exec("print ord(\"ā\")"); // outputs 63
```

I can't seem to find a way how to pass the string to the interpreter without messing those characters up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain exactly what happens, but it works for me if a unicode object is used as argument to `ord()` and if the Python code is compiled to a PyCode object:

```
import org.python.core.PyException;
import org.python.core.PyCode;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws PyException {

    PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
    System.out.println("ā".codePointAt(0));    // outputs 257
    interp.exec("print ord('ā')");             // outputs 63

    String s = "print ord(u'ā')";
    PyCode code = interp.compile(s);
    interp.exec(code);                         // outputs 257
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @mzjn, approach like this was suggested by the nice people at Jython-users list [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jython/mailman/message/31474668). With that insight, I could move on. However, Jython still fails at running code like `print u"\u0101"`, using your approach or the one suggested by Jim in the list.